# learning ACID-compliant transactions

Tags: mysql

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfB0c.jpg

Hi everyone,
I've been learning MySQL (exclusively, no experience with PHP yet) from Wiley's MySQL Administrator's Bible. I apologize in advance if any of the errors I come up appear to be child's play to you, but I figured that there'd be no harm in coming here to help polish my studying...

So, just cutting to the chase here - I attempted to demonstrate to myself the "Atomicity" and "Consistency" aspects of an ACID-compliant transaction. Pretty basic. However, when trying to force an error by having money be transferred from account ID 2 to a nonexistant '3', the transaction refused to revert to its previous state, and now poor Hudson is $5000 short after I committed. Can anyone point out why this is so? Thanks!

I look forward to becoming a regular here,

-MyPreQL

Comment: It would help if we could see the code you used to try to demonstrate it.

Comment: Try to insert and format your code into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still ran a COMMIT on your transaction. When you have an error, you want to ROLLBACK instead.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! I attempted to ROLLBACK; after the commit, but Hudson's account remains to be 10000. I understand that COMMIT is meant to make the changes durable, but does that include changes that are successful even though they work on nonexistent rows? To put it simply - what kind of failure would it have taken for my transaction to automatically rollback to the beginning?

Comment: You want to ROLLBACK *instead of* COMMIT. Not ROLLBACK *after* COMMIT. In the scenario you've set up, there's no "automatic" way to initiate a ROLLBACK. You need code to detect that the second update affected 0 rows and respond accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I understand completely now.

Answer (score 2):

Also. And I know this is trivial but it has not been mentioned and it is still a common mistake. Make sure your tables are engine type innoDB not MyIsam. Otherwise all those commits and rollbacks will look fine but be ineffective since MyIsam doesn't support transactions and cannot be ACID compliant :)